# Difference between Sqoop1.4.4 and 1.4.5

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

I am using Sqoop1.4.5. I need the difference between sqoop 1.4.4 and sqoop 1.4.5.
Please Help me to know the characteristics between these two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the release notes for sqoop 1.4.5: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/sqoop-1.4.5.releasenotes.html 
It lists everything that is included in 1.4.5, but not in 1.4.4.

Looking through it quickly, some of the most noteable changes are in the new features section:

> [SQOOP-767] - Add support for Accumulo
>
> [SQOOP-1051] - Support direct mode connection managers in a generalized fashion
>
> [SQOOP-1197] - Enable Sqoop to build against Hadoop-2.1.0-beta jar files
>
> [SQOOP-1287] - Add high performance Oracle connector into Sqoop